# Как проинициализировать шаблон JsRender, не передавая в него данные?

Tags: javascript, jsrender

Использую [JsRender](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrender).

Есть 2 варианта как рендерю элементы.

Первый: когда получаю аяксом данные в `json` формате, я подставляю в маркеры значения.
Второй: когда просто рендерю новый элемент без данных. Так вот на этом этапе мне выдает ошибку.

Как правильно задать условие, чтобы шаблонизатор подставлял значения, когда оно есть?

```
<script id="holidaysFormTpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="tr for-clone item active">
        <div class="td parent">
            <div class="wrapp-input  edit">
                <input type="text" class="input-val" name="name" placeholder="Christmas" value="{{if name}} {{:name}} {{/if}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="td parent">
            <div class="wrapp-input  edit">
                <input type="text" id="choose_date" name="start_date" value="{{:start_date}}" class="date-pick" placeholder="Choose date">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="td right-align">
            <a href="#" class="btn waves-effect waves-light ml-10 small  save-this-row">Save it</a>
        </div>
        <div class="td right-align">
            <a href="#" class="trash-ico "><span class="ico icon-trash "></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

---

```
//GENERATE DINAMIC HOLIDAYS BLOCK
    $('.add-hol').click(function(){
        var holidaysForm = $('#holidaysFormTpl').render();

        $(this).parents('.parent-form').find('.display-table .tbody').append(holidaysForm);
        initializeDtepicker2();
    });

//GET HOLIDAYS
    $('#dep-box').on('click', '.show-holidays', function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        var id = btn.parents('form').data('dep-id');

        $.ajax({
            url : '/settings/get_holidays',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id : id },
            success: function(data){
                var holidaysForm = $('#holidaysFormTpl').render(data);
                $('.holidays-box .display-table .tbody').append(holidaysForm);    
                initializeDtepicker2();

            }
        });
    });
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Если нужно проинициализировать шаблон без передачи данных, необходимо передать в метод `render` пустой объект. Вот так:

```js
var template = $.templates("#holidaysFormTpl");
var htmlOutput = template.render({});
$("#result").html(htmlOutput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrender/0.9.72/jsrender.min.js"></script>
<script id="holidaysFormTpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <div class="tr for-clone item active">
    <div class="td parent">
      <div class="wrapp-input  edit">
        <input type="text" class="input-val" name="name" placeholder="Christmas" value="{{if name}} {{:name}} {{/if}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="td parent">
      <div class="wrapp-input  edit">
        <input type="text" id="choose_date" name="start_date" value="{{:start_date}}" class="date-pick" placeholder="Choose date">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="td right-align">
      <a href="#" class="btn waves-effect waves-light ml-10 small  save-this-row">Save it</a>
    </div>
    <div class="td right-align">
      <a href="#" class="trash-ico "><span class="ico icon-trash "></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Проверьте свой код на наличие опечаток или уточните вопрос.

Comment: У меня есть момент когда я не передаю в render никакой даты,в этом случае выдается ошибка что name не существуе,поэтому можно ли условие прописать если есть name подставлять!

Comment: @quaresma89, отредактируйте вопрос и покажите пример data, на котором можно воспроизвести ошибку, а еще лучше добавьте и текст ошибки

Comment: Поправил вопрос!

Comment: @quaresma89 совсем не передавать данные не выйдет. Нужно в метод `render` передать пустой объект. Посмотрите ответ

Comment: Так и думал спасибо!